# WPF C# - Editing a listbox from another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I realize what I'm doing is probably pretty silly, but I'm in the middle of learning WPF and would like to know how to do this.

I have a window with a listbox on it. The listbox is being used to deliver status messages about the program while it's running. For example "Server started" "New connection at IP #" etc. I wanted this to be constantly updating in the background, so I spawned a new thread for handling updating this, but when I made the call to add an item I get the error message "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Any idea how I can update the listbox from another thread? Or in the background, etc.

Comment: I'm too sleepy to write a complete answer, but here's a hint: look around (Google, SO, or MSDN) for Dispatcher. Now, I'm off to bed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

---

*UPDATE*

If you are using C# 5 and .NET 4.5 or above you can avoid getting on another thread in the first place using `async` and `await`, e.g.:

```
private async Task<string> SimLongRunningProcessAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    return "Success";
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button.Content = "Running...";
    var result = await SimLongRunningProcessAsync();
    button.Content = result;
}
```

---

Easy:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate() 
  {
     myListBox.Items.Add("new item"));
  }));
```

If you are in code-behind. Otherwise you can access the Dispatcher (which is on every `UIElement`) using:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...
```

Ok thats a lot in one line let me go over it:

When you want to update a UI control you, as the message says, have to do it from the UI thread. There is built in way to pass a delegate (a method) to the UI thread: the `Dispatcher`. Once you have the `Dispatcher` you can either `Invoke()` of `BeginInvoke()` passing a delegate to be run on the UI thread. The only difference is `Invoke()` will only return once the delegate has been run (i.e. in your case the ListBox's new item has been added) whereas `BeginInvoke()` will return immediately so your other thread you are calling from can continue (the Dispatcher will run your delegate soon as it can which will probably be straight away anyway).

I passed an anonymous delegate above:

```
delegate() {myListBox.Items.Add("new item");}
```

The bit between the {} is the method block. This is called anonymous because only one is created and it doesnt have a name (usually you can do this using a lambda expression but in this case C# cannot resolve the BeginInvoke() method to call). Or I could have instantiated a delegate:

```
Action myDelegate = new Action(UpdateListMethod);

void UpdateListMethod() 
{
  myListBox.Items.Add("new item");
}
```

Then passed that:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(myDelegate);
```

I also used the Action class which is a built in delegate but you could have created your own - you can read up more about delegates on MSDN as this is going a bit off topic..

Comment: Hey thanks, I really appreciate detailed explanation! I'm a programming student, but everyone at my school has a dislike of C#. I like your longer explanation since it's helping me to understand what's going on. C# and WPF is a fairly huge language, and there's only so much I can get straight out of a book.

Comment: My pleasure (it is v. similar to another answer I have given). Pls mark it as the answer if it is :)

Comment: I like how, looking back on this three years later, I actually know what a dispatcher, invoking, delegates, and all this other stuff is (and actually know how to use it!) :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the Action delegate with anonymous methods to update the main thread from the worker thread. For more information on the Action class you could look here :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx

If you would like to update the listbox from multiple points I suggest explicitally setting the delegate, however if you just wish to update the thread at a single point in a method with a single call it could be done as follows :

```
        listbox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
        {
            listbox.Items.Add(item); //where item is the item to be added and listbox is the control being updated.
        }));
```

Note that I use the Action class as it takes encapsulates a method that has a single parameter (in this case a listItem).

Comment: I think this does it. The other answer that was given gave me a compiler error about how it couldn't convert the lamba calculus to a delegate. I did some reading on the msdn site and googled how to work with the dispatcher; I modified the code he gave me and it turned out looking exactly like what you've got there. Answered 13 minutes ago, I should've just hit refresh, haha.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx). For example, if the listbox is named `listbox`

```
  // On worker thread
  listbox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
  new Action(delegate() { listbox.Items.Add("Server started") });
```

This will queue up the delegate to be executed on the UI thread that `listbox` belongs to.

Comment: Hey thanks, you pointed in the right direction, but the complier didn't like what you gave here. Gave an error about how it can't convert lamba calculus to a delegate. I was able to change it around so it works, any idea what was off about yours, or were you just using notation I don't understand

Comment: No I was just too lazy to check myself with an actual program.