# WPF : Accessing a UI object with a Thread gives an error

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, multithreading

I have a function that is called when a file is modified in a folder. This function updates the items of a listview which is stored in the UI.

Here is the function :

```
Private Sub FileChangeNotify()
    Try
        LstMoulures.Items.Refresh()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Ex.exception)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Here is the error: "Le thread appelant ne peut pas accéder à cet objet parce qu'un autre thread en est propriétaire." (Translation : The calling thread cannot access this object because it is owned by another thread)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub FileChangeNotify()
  LstMoulures.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke (New Action(AddressOf LstMoulures.Items.Refresh))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot modify objects in the UI thread directly from another thread - check out the `BeginInvoke` method, which lets you access UI objects across threads.

Check out [WPF C# - Editing a listbox from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191325/wpf-c-editing-a-listbox-from-another-thread)